# Different conditions for self-adjoint property

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-adjoint-operators

Consider the following differential equation
$$f(x)\partial_ty(x,t)+\hat{M}y(x,t)=0\,,$$
where $\hat{M}$ is a differential operator with respect to $x$ and assume $y(x,t)=T(t)v(x)$.
Then,
$$f(x)T'(t)v(x)+\hat{M}v(x)T(t)=0$$
and hence
$$\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=-\frac{\hat{M}v(x)}{f(x)v(x)}=\mathrm{const.}\equiv -\lambda\,.$$
We thus find
$$\hat{M}v(x)=\lambda f(x) v(x)$$
and
$$T'(t)+\lambda T(t)=0\,.$$
For $f\equiv\mathrm{const.}$, $\hat{M}$ is self-adjoint with the corresponding boundary conditions.
In the literature (Rao, Singiresu S. Vibration of continuous systems. John Wiley & Sons, 2007.), I find the following conditions for self-adjointness (for arbitrary (multiplication) operators $f(x)$)
$$\int\mathrm{d}x\,u_1(x)\hat{M}u_2(x)=\int\mathrm{d}x\,u_2(x)\hat{M}u_1(x)$$
and simultaneously
$$\int\mathrm{d}x\,u_1(x)f(x)u_2(x)=\int\mathrm{d}x\,u_2(x)f(x)u_1(x)\,.$$
The question now is, how can this be true, where I can write the eigenvalue equation in the following way
$$\frac{1}{f(x)}\hat{M}v(x)=\lambda v(x)$$
and so define a new operator $\hat{\tilde{M}}\equiv \frac{1}{f(x)}\hat{M}$, which is no more neccessarily self-adjoint with the corresponding boundary conditions as I will get derivatives of $f$ during partial integration?

I appreciate any help, thanks.